# 23.04 Ubuntu cannot access WIN 10 network shared fil

Tags: networking, network-manager

I have just completed a very successful Ubuntu 23.04 install. Managing to easily get the WiFi network up  accessing home network Internet, Chromecast etc.. and with some little effort got the EPSON printer drivers installed and it running too.

However the last bastion, that of accessing the shared network HDD running on my WIN 10 PC has escaped me. Whilst I can see the network HDD in Ubuntu files and or in terminal,  all I get is 'file empty' message trying to access the file.

Without success, I have tried all manner of terminal code and samba config changes as instructed on the different web sites, ask Ubuntu included. Most seem to be coming at the problem from a Windows network access issue as opposed to my issue that of Ubuntu accessing a shared Windows network file.

I am relatively new to Ubuntu any assist with my issue would really be appreciated.

Comment: Just to be clear: you can see the files on the shared partition, but they appear empty? Or is it just one particular file that appears empty? Can you create a file, or a folder?

Comment: Hey tks for the prompt follow up,,, OK what I see when I open files in Ubuntu is;

Comment: Ooops hit return too soon again what I see when I click on other places in Ubuntu file is a Windows Network globe icon. If I click on the globe icon I get the message 'File Empty' ,

Comment: Oh BTW I can see the Ubuntu laptop on the network and access the files on the laptop from WIN 10 PC.

Comment: Have you installed `cifs-utils`? I believe this is necessary in order to access a Samba share.

Comment: Tks Jos, no I have not installed cifs-utils. I will do so and advise cheers

Comment: OK so cifs-utils has installed successfully,,,, what now ?

Comment: Scratch my last,,, got it...

Comment: No I haven't,,,,, I have absolutely no idea as to how to use the cifs-util to make a file that comes up as 'Windows Network' globe in Ubuntu file manager accessible. A lot of the script commands I have reviewed from the WEB assume I have a in depth working knowledge of all the variable and parameter script commands,,, which I do not.

Comment: The variables and parameters are for hosting a server on Linux, which can be tricky (mainly because it's so versatile) but you don't: The server is Windows. It should be as simple as clicking "Connect to server" in Files, as explained here: https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001636.htm

Comment: Hey tks heaps Jos, all sorted,,, cheers

Comment: @jos It looks like your answer successfully allowed OP to solve their problem. Can you add as an answer? And Vert…please check that as the successful answer if jos adds an answer.

Comment: Sure happy to, how do I do that ? There is no check box to indicate answer solved my problem.

Comment: Issue is resolved, tks Jos and to all those who contributed to answering this question. The solution simple as it was albeit hard at the time is to make sure Network share is turned on in sharing then add the network drive address e.g. smb://asus-p5g41t-mlx/hdd1/ to the connect option in Files and viola access working without a hitch. Issue Closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install `cifs-utils` in order to access a Windows shared folder on a Ubuntu system. The shared folder will then turn up under "Windows network".

You don't need to install the full Samba stack (as I think you tried). That is only necessary if you want to do it the other way around: access a shared Ubuntu folder from Windows, or from another Ubuntu system. You are correct, that is tricky, because Samba gives you a lot of control over how your shared folder can be accessed, and by whom.